# Url enviado por email mediante PHP

Tags: php, url

estoy creando una página que requiere que el usuario inicie sesión con un usuario. Para recuperar la contraseña estoy enviando un email con el url para la recuperación de la contraseña. en el url paso la variable, esta variable esta creada por caracteres de números y letras aleatoreos sin espacios. Hasta ahí todo bien, sin embargo al recibir el email noté que el url ha cambiado y me ingresa otros caracteres cerca al final de la variable. Ejemplo:envio ?url=123456789 y recibo ?url=1234%05%6789 ¿Como se puede solucionar este error?

La función que uso para generar la variable aleatoria es la siguiente:

```
function sa($longitud){
$caracteres = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$numero_caracteres = strlen($caracteres);
$string_aleatorio='';
for ($i = 0; $i < $longitud; $i++){
    $string_aleatorio = $caracteres[rand(0, $numero_caracteres -1)];
}
return $string_aleatorio;
```

}

Luego, en esta zona del código uso la función para codificarla con el email, almacenar en la base de datos y enviarla:

```
$string_aleatorio = sa(15);
    $url=hash('sha256',$string_aleatorio.$email);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO recuperacion (id_usuario, '
            . 'urlSecret, estado, fecha) VALUES (:id_usuario, '
            . ':urlSecret, "0", now())');
    $stmt->execute([
        ':id_usuario'=>$row['id_usuario'],
        ':urlSecret'=>$url
    ]);
    include_once 'Scripts/EmailRecuperacion.inc.php';
```

Y el codigo de EmailRecuperacio.inc.php es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$destinatario= $email;
$asunto="Recuperación de contraseña";

$cabeceras  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$cabeceras .= 'To: >'. $destinatario . '>' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'From: MedicionCO2-USCO' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Cc: dominio.com/' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Bcc: dominio.com/' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n';

$message = '<html><head>';
$message .= '<meta charset="UTF-8">';
$message .= '<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Muli|Open+Sans|PT+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">';
$message .= '<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">';
 $message .= '<link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">';
$message .= '</head>';
$message .= '<body style="background:#ffffff;margin:0px;padding:0px;width:100%;margin:0px;font-family:"Muli",sans-serif;">';
$message .= '<div style="padding:0px;margin:0px;background:#8f1b20;border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;">';
$message .= '<div style="color:#e4d4a4;">';
$message .= '<h1 style="padding:10px;">Medicion CO2 - USCO</h1>';
$message .= '</div>';
$message .= '<div style="padding:10px;height:100%;color:#FFF8F0;background-color:#b47464;border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;">';
$message .= '<h3>Recuperación de contraseña</h3>';
$message .= '<p>Para recuperar la contraseña de ingreso da click ';
$message .= '<a style="padding:0px;margin:0px;text-decoration:none;color:#8f1b20;"href="http://dominio.com/Recuperacion_clave.php?url='.$url.'">aqui</a></p>';
$message .= '</p></div></div></body></html>';    

$registroCorrecto=mail($destinatario, $asunto, $message, $cabeceras);
```

Comment: ¿Cómo creas la url que envías? Añade el código para que podamos ayudarte, puedes ver cómo preguntar en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Parece que estuviera codificando algún caracter: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP.

Comment: Vale, ahí te adjunté todo lo que uso. Lo extraño es que al crear cuenta uso practicamente el mismo código, solo cambio variables y funciona sin problemas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se porque o como, pero el error era la ultima linea de $message; simplemente separe la cadena de caracteres de esta manera y funcionó:

```
$message .= '</p>';
$message .= '</div></div></body></html>';
```

De todos modos gracias por la ayuda, sirvió para entender que pasaba

Answer (score 0):

Con el código no logro reproducir el problema, no genera caracteres especiales que codifique la url del navegador con ese aspecto (ver ejemplos [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)). Revisa si el campo email contiene algún carácter que pueda ser el origen, como espacios, paréntesis, asteriscos, ...

Como en tu caso envías el email con `charset=iso-8859-1` y luego el mensaje con `charset="UTF-8"`, podría deberse al cambio de un charset a otro. Puedes comprobarlo si estas en iso-8859-1 convirtiendo a UTF-8 con `utf8_encode($url)`.

Por otro lado, creo que tienes un error en la función sa, tal como está da lugar a una cadena de un único caracter.

```
   function sa($longitud){
    $caracteres = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $numero_caracteres = strlen($caracteres);
    $string_aleatorio='';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $longitud; $i++){
        $string_aleatorio = $caracteres[rand(0, $numero_caracteres -1)];
    }
    return $string_aleatorio;

   }

$string_aleatorio = sa(15); //Resultado: M
```

La idea supongo que es ir añadiendo caracteres en cada vuelta del bucle for, asi que dentro del `for` debería ser

```
$string_aleatorio .= $caracteres[rand(0, $numero_caracteres -1)];

$string_aleatorio = sa(15); //Resultado: MaswKg30s7Xwp1V
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.